# Is $f(x) = 2 + \ln x$ another way to write $f(x) =\log_e x +2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I just want to make sure I am correctly understaning this concept.

> $f(x) = 2 + \ln x$  is the same as $f(x) =\log_e x +2$

Thus my T graph would look like so:

### e^y|x+2

-3|2.049

-2|2.135

-1|2.36

Is this correct?

Comment: could you use LaTeX ? so we could see what you mean with "loge(x)"

Comment: $f(x)=2+\ln{x}=\log_e{x}+2$ is correct but the meaning of the table you gave escapes me. What is the purpose of the $e^y$ column?  Also, there is no $x+2$ in the expression.  I think perhaps you have set $y=f(x)$ and then incorrectly manipulated the equation to get $e^y=x+2$? No criticism, just puzzled.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I see what is going on. I will be back momentarily with an answer. (even if one has been posted)

Answer (score 2):

**Facts**
\[ y=2+\ln x \]
\[ e^{y}=e^{2+\ln x}=e^{2}e^{\ln x}=e^{2}x \]
**T-Graph**
\[
\begin{array}{c|l}
x & e^{2}x \\
\hline
e^{-1} & e^{2}e^{-1} =e^{1} \\
e^{-2} & e^{2}e^{-2}=1 \\
e^{-3} & e^{2}e^{-3}=e^{-1} \\
\end{array}
\]

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Contrary to what people have stated it is NOT correct to say $f(x)=2+ln(x)= log_e(x+2)$. The miscommunication on the communities part is that it is correct that $f(x)=2+ln(x) = 2+ log_e(x)$. It is very important to indicate what the logarithm is acting on! That is why we use parentheses. Without them, we indicate that the logarithm affects only the first letter, variable, number, etc. and the rest is continuing with order of operations.

So the T-chart that you made is not correct, but it is a good step.
Instead, replace it with $e^y$ and $e^{(log_e(x)+2)}=e^{log_e(x)}*e^2 = x*e^2$. Try to replace these values in your column.